# Let $G$ be a group. Show that if $H$ is subgroup of $G$ then $HG'$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

This is my homework question and my solution is;

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

$G'$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ whose quotient $G/G'$ is abelian.

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/N$ is abelian, then $G'$ is a subgroup of $N$.

Hence, as $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $G'≤H≤G$ and then $H$ is a normal subgroup of *G*.

$ghg^{-1} \in H$ for all $g \in G$ and for all $h \in H$

($[g,h]$ is called a commutator, $G'$ is commutator subgroup of $G$)

*$ghg$$^{-1}$*=$ghg^{-1}(h^{-1} h)=[g,h]h$ and then $G'≤H$

And I know that $G'$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/G'$ is abelian.

But I am stuck, I would appreciate it if you help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not following your proof. How are you going from "If N is normal subgroup of G and G/N is abelian, then G' is subgroup of N." to "Hence, as H is subgroup of G, G'≤H≤G", given that we know nothing about whether $H$ is normal, or whether $G/H$ is abelian?

Comment: "If N is normal subgroup of G and G/N is abelian, then G' is subgroup of N." in my lecture notes and I think that it is useful for this question.

Comment: Yes, that's true. What I don't see is how you're applying it: $H$ is not necessarily normal, and $G/H$, if it even exists, is not necessarily abelian.

Comment: Also, the title is somehow about $HG'$ ...

Comment: Let H be a subgroup of G. G' is the smallest normal subgroup of G and then G'≤H≤G. then H is normal subgroup of G. Is it false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had it in your post, though a bit messy. Let me order your thoughts.

**Proposition** If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ with $G' \subseteq H$, then $H$ is normal.

**Corollary** For any subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, $HG'$ is a normal subgroup.
**Proof** Since $G'$ is normal, $HG'$ is certainly a subgroup, and of course $G' \subseteq HG'$.

So let's prove the proposition: let $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, then $g^{-1}hg=h(h^{-1}g^{-1}hg)=h[h,g]$ and $[h,g] \in G' \subseteq H$ and of course $h \in H$, so their product is also in $H$.$\square$

Comment: Thank you!! :))

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the image of $H$ under the canonical map $ G\to G/G'$. As $G/G'$ is abelian, every subgroup is normal, so that we can consider $(G/G')/A$.

Now guess what the kernel of $G\to (G/G')/A$ is (and then prove that you guessed right).